# Excel - Conditional Filtering

Tags: excel

I've a table of orders within Excel their associated products and order dates. For example:

```
Date            Product          Quantity

11/02/2013      A                12
12/02/2014      B                12
12/02/2014      B                12
```

What I need to find out is, which products were ordered the first time after 2013. In 'pseudo-sql' this would look like:

```
SELECT PRODUCT FROM ORDERS WHERE NOT EXISTS DATE < 2013.
```

I'm not so well versed in these types of conditionals in Excel, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pivot table will give you the information you need.

Highlight your data, including the header row, click "Pivot Table" from the "Insert" ribbon, and select "OK."

In the "Pivot Table Field List," drag "Product" to the "Row Labels" section and drag "Date" to the "Values" section.

Click the arrow next to "Date" in the "Values" section, and select "Value Field Settings." Select the "Min" function and click "OK."

Now, click on any value in the "Min of Date" column of the pivot table and select "Sort" from the "Data" ribbon. Choose "Smallest to Largest" and click "OK."

What you now have is a listing of all of your products, ordered by the earliest order date of each product. Scroll to 2013; products listed on all successive rows were initially ordered in 2013 or later.

Comment: @james_dean Sure thing. Take care.